# Error launching Spyder from Anaconda Navigator - “chcp 1254..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, anaconda3

```
C:\Users\engoc>chcp 1254
Active code page: 1254

C:\Users\engoc>call C:\Users\engoc\anaconda3\Scripts\activate C:\Users\engoc\anaconda3

(base) C:\Users\engoc>spyder  1>nul 2>nul
```

This terminal window appears, then closes itself and Spyder along with it.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to launch spyder from the terminal and not through anaconda navigator?

Comment: Yes ,it opens...